# (entrance) as a location in Goals for Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, goals

When I'm looking at Conversions > Goals > Goal urls some of the goal completion locations says `(entrance)`. It's not very helpful and I'm wondering why it says that. What does it mean?

Comment: Is it an event goal or a destination goal you are tracking? If it's an event goal, then what could be happening is that the page is not being sent, so GA reverts to (entrance).

Answer (score 1):

This answer to your question sounds identical to this answer for a question on stackoverflow.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/26317218/1569370
>
> "(entrance)" indicates the page which served as an entry point to your
>   site. It could be that when you set up your URL goal, you didn't have
>   any funnel steps, so when a user arrives at your site, they arrive
>   directly at the goal completion URL. It's not something that can be
>   removed. Rather you would just have to add funnel steps to your goal.

Comment: Hey there! If this is a duplicated question, then it should be flagged as such instead of being answered as such. Thanks.

Comment: @nyuen Thanks for the suggestion. When I tried to flag it as a duplicate, I wasn't able to pull up the stackoverflow answer. It looks like it will only link to other webmasters posts.